# how to insert a video into Oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle, blob

i need to insert a video into oracle database , and here is what i'm trying to do , i wanna know if it is right
i have created this table :

```
CREATE TABLE video (vid_id number
                   ,vid_name varchar2(100)
                   ,video BLOB) ;
```

the control file is like this :

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'video.txt'
INTO TABLE tab1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(id  ,
 video_filename    FILLER CHAR(100),
 videoLOBFILE(video_filename) TERMINATED BY EOF)
```

The video.txt file is like this

`1,vid.mp4`

I come along this in a tutorial used for storing a picture , what I don't understand is how it's gonna know the path of the video?

Comment: What error(s) do you get when you try?  If `vid.mp4` isn't in the current directory when you invoke `SQL*Loader`, you'd need to specify the full path in your data file.

Comment: what is this? Oracle forms or something? Can you edit your tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use PL/SQL to do that, not SQL*Loader. Here's an example.

Connected as `SYS`, create directory (Oracle object that points to filesystem directory that contains the file) and grant privileges to user who will be loading the file:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> create directory ext_dir as 'c:\temp';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory ext_dir to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Connect as `scott`; create target table, load the file:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create table test (id number, movie blob);

Table created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_dir    varchar2(10) := 'EXT_DIR';
  3    l_file   varchar2(20) := 'movie.mp4';
  4    l_bfile  bfile;
  5    l_blob   blob;
  6  begin
  7    insert into test (id, movie)
  8      values (1, empty_blob())
  9      return movie into l_blob;
 10
 11    l_bfile := bfilename(l_dir, l_file);
 12    dbms_lob.fileopen(l_bfile, dbms_lob.file_readonly);
 13    dbms_lob.loadfromfile(l_blob, l_bfile, dbms_lob.getlength(l_bfile));
 14    dbms_lob.fileclose(l_bfile);
 15
 16  end;
 17  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select dbms_lob.getlength(movie) from test;

DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(MOVIE)
-------------------------
                  1570024

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , does this instruction (l_dir    varchar2(10) := 'EXT_DIR'; ) mean the directory of the video im my system , or the directory we have created in oracle ?

Comment: You're welcome. EXT_DIR is name of Oracle directory (that's what I created as the 1st part of code I posted). Physical directory is C:\TEMP

Comment: i understand , thanks for your time !

Comment: No problem; I'm glad if it helped.

Comment: i'm having a problem with the user Scott u have used ,i actually get an error while granting priveliges @littlefoot

Comment: here is the error : user or role 'SCOTT' does not exist

Comment: You should grant privileges (and be connected as) user which exists in your database. I used sample SCOTT schema, so - obviously - I used SCOTT. I don't know which user you have, but you should.

Comment: i have created a new user and it worked , thank you !

Comment: what's the point of connection between two users sysdba and scott , why not only use only one ?

Comment: Because you should **not**, EVER, do anything (apart from system administration) using SYS or SYSTEM users.

Comment: okay , got it thank you